# JS function to generate unique random number

Tags: javascript

I have the following utility function:

```
var Utilities = (function (array, maxN) {

  function generateRandomNumber(array, maxN) {
        let randomN = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxN - 0) + 0);

        if(array.length == maxN) {
            array = [];
        }

        if(!array.includes(randomN)) {
            array.push(randomN);
        }
        else {
            randomN = generateRandomNumber(array, maxN);
        }
        return randomN;
    }

    return {
        generateRandomNumber: generateRandomNumber
    };

})();

export default Utilities;
```

which I am using like so:

```
function getRandomNumber() {
    var array = [];
    let randomN = Utilities.generateRandomNumber(array, 5);
    return randomN;
}
```

I am then using this function inside a react component like so:

```
...

    getNewQuestion = () => {
        var randomN = getRandomNumber();
        console.log(randomN);
        this.setState({
            question: this.state.data.data.questions[randomN]
        })
        this.setCatBgColor(this.state.data.data.questions[randomN].category);
    }

...
```

I have just made a test and I got:

0,0,3

which is wrong as they should be unique until the length of 5 (in this case) is reached.

Comment: `- 0`, `+ 0`…?!

Comment: @deceze Nah, all the zeroes are positive

Comment: @Bergi I should have used more words here: *what are those `- 0` and `+ 0` doing there in your code…? Looks pretty superfluous.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function

```
function getRandomNumber() {
    var array = [];
    let randomN = Utilities.generateRandomNumber(array, 5);
    return randomN;
}
```

does create a new empty `array` on every call, not remembering anything. `generateRandomNumber` won't know about the previous invocations. Put the variable declaration and initialisation outside of the function:

```
var array = [];
function getRandomNumber() {
    return Utilities.generateRandomNumber(array, 5);
}
```